# How can I execute different Jquery ajax callbacks depending on response code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, promise

What I really want to know is the correct way to execute different Jquery ajax callbacks depending on various response codes that might be returned from the back end, for example if 200 then, if 401 then if some other code then do something else.

I am a javascript beginner.

I'm trying to allow the user to save an image to the back end using ajax, and if they are not registered, it automatically registers and saves the image.

I have built a solution its not doing the autoregister.

I think I'm out of my depth, way off track and lost amongst the Ajax Jquery promises and callbacks.

Here's the pseudocode:

```
    users executes save image ajax function
    if response is 200 OK then:
        update page
        finish
    if response is 401 not authorised then:
        execute autoregister ajax function
        try again to save image (not more than 2 retries)
    if some other http error
        alert error to user
        finish
```

Here is the current function:

```
    // after the image is cropped this saves it to the back end
    function saveCroppedImage() {
        $.ajax({type:'post',
            url:'/app/api/images/uploadfrompost/',
            data: { image: _croppedImage, imageid: elementCurrentlyBeingCropped},
            statusCode: {
            401: function() {
                tryCount = 0,
                retryLimit = 3,
                console.log( "401, not authenticated, registering new." );
              if (tryCount <= retryLimit) {
                registerAnon();
                // try again to save image
                tryCount++;
                $.ajax(this);
                }
               }
              }
            })
            .always(function(data) {
                            //refresh all the schedule images with the newly uploaded image
                            });
                        // display previous modal
                        $('#uploadModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
                    });

    }


function registerAnon() {
    return $.ajax({type:'GET',
        async:   false,
        url:'/app/api/users/registeranon/'
     });
}
```

Comment: You can't execute different callbacks, but the callback receives the `jqXHR` object as an argument, and you can get the response code from that. Then it can use `if` or `switch` to do different things.

Comment: BTW, `401:` is not a valid property in an object literal. You need to put it in quotes: `"401":`.

Comment: @Barmar Incorrect. It would be invalid in JSON, but is valid for an object literal, and is the way the [jQuery Ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) have it defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var tryCount = 0,
    retryLimit = 3;

function saveCroppedImage() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/app/api/images/uploadfrompost/",
        data: { image: _croppedImage, imageid: elementCurrentlyBeingCropped },
    })
};

saveCroppedImage()
.always(function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // `error`
  if (textStatus !== "success" &&  jqxhr.status === 401) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown, tryCount, retryLimit);
    registerAnon();
    ++tryCount;
    $("#uploadModal").foundation("reveal", "close"); // always do stuff
    // call `savedCroppedImage` if `401` error occurs again ,
    // and `tryCount` less than `retryLimit`
    (function check(tc, rl) {
      if (tc < rl) {
        saveCroppedImage().always(function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          // `error`
          if (textStatus !== "success" && jqxhr.status === 404) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown, tc, rl);
            ++tc;
            tryCount = tc;
            $("#uploadModal").foundation("reveal", "close"); // always do stuff
            check(tc, rl);
          } 
          // `success`
          else {
            console.log(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
          }
        }) 
      }
    }(tryCount, retryLimit))
  } 
  // `success` 
  // `jqxhr`:`data`, `errorThrown`:`jqxhr`
  else {
    console.log(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
  }
});

function registerAnon() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: "/app/api/users/registeranon/"
    });
};
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/qab212s5/